# Declare instance variable in Swift : optional vs forced unwrapping vs initial value

Tags: ios, swift, initialization, instance-variables

This is a basic question about the best practice in swift to declare a swift class with instance variable, all the values will be received from Firebase callback. What is the best approach among these choices or let me know if there another better way:

Solution 1:

```
class User: NSObject {
    var name:String = ""

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }
}
```

Solution 2:

```
class User: NSObject {
    var name:String!

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }   
}
```

Solution 3:

```
class User: NSObject {
    var name:String?

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }   
}
```

Solution 4:

```
class User: NSObject {

    var name:String

    override init() {
        super.init()
        // Now I need to init name variable here
    } 
}
```

Comment: Don't use `!` if you don't need 2-phase initialization or interaction with Obj-C. Don't use optionals if you don't need `nil` values.  That's basically all you need to know.

Answer (score 4):

Using implicitly unwrapped optionals is almost never a good idea. You should be thinking like this: If you are sure that you will always have `name` of the `User` you should initialize object with `name` string like this:

```
class User: NSObject {
    let name: String
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
        super.init()
    }
}
```

If you are not sure that you will get `name` in the callback use optional string property:

```
class User: NSObject {
    var name: String?
}
```

This will enable you to use `if let` to check if `name` has a value.

If you use `String!`, your application will almost certainly crash at one point because you accessed `nil`.

`var name: String = ""` is also misleading because you would have to implement checking if string is empty or contains name.

Comment: I like the first choice but in that case I need to init all variables and I will have all that long init method, and in real life I will have a dictionary or an another object how to get rid of the warning   `Property 'self.name' not initialized at super.init call`

Comment: Your answer is good, but you've got the names of the two types of optionals the wrong way round - **?** is **explicit**, **!** is **implicit**. So the first line of your post should read 'Using *implicitly* unwrapped optionals . . . - see http://andybargh.com/optionals-in-swift/#Implicitly_Unwrapped_Optionals

Comment: Thanks, typo on my part, fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

using something like

```
var name:String = ""
```

Is saying that you have the variable name that will be initialized to "" for all objects

```
var name:String?
```

Is saying that you know for a fact that the variable name will be in this object and that this name property can contain the value nil. Acknowledging its existence this way means you **must** initialize it before you use it. This gives you a bit more control. In most cases just having something like

```
String name;
```

In other languages means that if you were to use name without explicitly initializing it then you'll get an empty string. That's not the case here. With **?** you're saying that this property *name* definitely exists for all objects but it may or may not contain data, but since you explicitly created it using **?** then you know for a fact that at some point it **should** contain data.

```
var name:String!
```

This is kinda like var name:String = "" at the top of the file. With **!** you're saying that the moment you create an object you'll be able to use the name property because it's already been initialized. That's why IBOutlets have **!** and not **?**. The reason is because it's already been set up for you. It's initialized before you use it

The confusion between **?** and **!** come from not using them correctly. If you have total control of the project and you know when things are coming in and out of use and you're in control of when things are being created then it may be best to use **!**. In a perfectly controlled self-contained environment you'd want to use **!** because it'll be like the programming you're used to

But what if you start adding in interactions between view controllers that are conditional, and you know that at some point you're going to need a *name* property but you just don't know exactly when? Well you may say:

"Hey I could just use **!** and check to see if it contains "" or not"

and that could work and it'd be just fine but that takes up space if you go through the entire app without actually using that property in that instance. You're basically programming for all situations when most views are conditional.

That's why you'd go for **?**. **?** is saying that you need this property. You may not know when exactly but it definitely has a purpose. And you can still write logic with this property even if it doesn't exist because it allows you to check existence without checking for data. This fact is what makes optionals so great because when you compile your app, Xcode will be able to comb through it and see the optional flag. It'll then begin to handle the optional. This is important because what does

```
var name:String
```

Tell you about name? Has it been initialized? Will it be?

So then what would

```
print(name)
```

Mean to the compiler when it runs? Well, you won't know until you actually run it. This is an issue, but

```
print(name!)
```

Forces an unwrap of the optional **var name:String?**. This allows the compiler to prevent runtime errors because someone created a property that turned out to be *optional*.